# Wordpress How to to add images automatically to a custom post by image name?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a folder that i created that are filled using ftp.

To be enable to allocate witch photo should go to what post the photos are named with a unique custom field that the post is using.

For example
Custom post type = car >> each post in car have car license number (custom field), for example= 311111 >> wp-upload contains folder named car-photos >> the photo that feet this car post is named 311111-photo-01.jpg.

What I am trying to do is to create a php file that will work on cron job. 
The php file work is to get all the images in the specific folder,look for the same unique identifier as the post have (in a custom field) and create to this post a gallery from all the this photos.

This is hard for me to explain but hopefully you get me.. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: can you post your code what you have tried?

Comment: What you are asking is not a singleton function or some lines of code - but a full blown plugin. still I will try to answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is a whole plugin , not just a few lines of code - therefor i will describe the theory and important functions.
I have myself made a custom plugin for internal use that does a very similar thing .

Basically you need to scan your `car-photos` folder, then for each image found sanitize the name and then use [media_sideload_image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image) function ( or see equivalents below ) according to a query object match of posts by custom fields.

The [media_sideload_image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image) or [wp_handle_sideload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_sideload) and others like `media_handle_upload()`, `media_handle_sideload()`, `wp_handle_upload()`, `wp_import_handle_upload()`, `wp_handle_sideload()`, `media_sideload_image()` are the crutial part for this task - all are searchable in codex .

About cron - I myself have not implemented it using cron but with 2 different methods : 1 ) an execution on demand button and 2) a hook on some initial function that will execute every time the site is accessed ( or a specific url / page / theme file ). user can choose between the two methods .